# ArcGIS Online layer visibility range

Tags: arcgis-online, visibility

I am trying to change the visibility range for several layers on an ArcGIS web map - should be simple right??

This could be a case of my misunderstanding on how to use a tool or it could be a case of a bug.

I have tried to adjust the **Set Visibility Range** tool by moving the white arrows.  There is no save or OK button.  When I have clicked outside of the tool box and then back into the tool I see that it has not saved the scales I want.
[image: Visibility Range tool]

I would love to simply be able to write a minimum scale of 1:3000 and no maximum.

Does anyone have any suggestions how I can work around this?

The layer is a web service which is used within many of our maps so I cannot simply alter the visibility range before publishing the service. [This is the Service that I have been using.](http://gis.taupodc.govt.nz/arcgis/rest/services/Mapi/TaupoProperty/MapServer/0)

I had tried using the scale range under the change symbols option.  This appeared to work the first time but the settings did not save properly and later in the afternoon it was back to default.

I am using Chrome.

19/04/2016:  I have tried using the change symbol options using Internet Explorer 11 (used Chrome yesterday) but again it does not appear to save the scale I want.

28/04/2016:  The original service I linked to was the wrong service so I have corrected that link. 
I have trialed the service on a test map I have just created and this has worked fine.  The problem appears to be in my original online map.  As you can see in the screenshot above the scale bar goes off the chart.

15/09/2016:  I am still having issues with this same map.  I have added another layer that I wanted a limited visibility range for. Same errors happening, again this works fine in a blank map.  It appears that arcgis webmaps are easily corruptible.

Comment: Can you try setting the scale range under the change symbols option? Also what browser are you using?

Comment: I have just edited question to include the above questions.

Comment: Once u set your range, click on Save Layer in the context menu and make sure to save your map as well

Comment: What type of service are you using? Is there anyway you can share your service/map? Can you reproduce this on other services? thanks!

Comment: @RussRoberts I have added a link to the service that I was using.  I have now removed the service as it is surplus to my maps requirements but it would be great to have an answer for future use.

Comment: I think it could be your service. It looks like its missing the query capability under supported operations. You can see this under MapServer/0 at the bottom of the page.

Comment: http://arcg.is/23O5f9x Seems to be working ok for me?

Comment: @RussRoberts I have trialed the service on a test map and it is working fine.  It is within my specific map that I have the issue.